# UWP project TreeView class doesn't exist

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

Is it normal that TreeView, TreeViewItem, etc. classes don't exist in an UWP project ?
If I try to create an instance of these classes, Visual Studio 2017 tells me that "the type doesn't exist on the current context".

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: seems indeed not built in. but there are open source libraries: [1](http://www.mrlacey.com/2016/10/treeview-control-for-uwp-apps.html) [2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.uwp)

Comment: Is it a good idea to use tree-view UI structure on mobile devices? If your app are targeting small screen devices, you need to consider the user experience.

Comment: @LeiYang How can I use the first library after build it ?

Comment: @kennyzx This is not my choice

Comment: [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) for UWP is not released yet. If you want to use TreeView, You need to download [Windows Insider SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK) to access TreeView. Also You need to be on Insider Program to use this for now. This control will be available in Fall Creator's Update Release

Answer (score 0):

You can do TreeView natively in UWP with the Spring Creators Update Windows 10, version 1803:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view

Comment: For `TreeView` to be available you need to go to the properties page of your UWP project and choose as "Target version" at "Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134)" or newer.